# Changing the Password format in Membership

Tags: asp.net

How do I change the required password format in membership?

Comment: Do you mean the format of the passwords that users must follow? or the format in which the passwords are stored in the database?

Comment: i mean the format of the passwords that users must follow

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx :

In your `web.config` :

```
<system.web>
...
  <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
        name="SqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
        applicationName="MyApplication"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

Modify `passwordFormat` to what you'd like :

> The SQL Server membership provider
>   supports Clear, Encrypted, and Hashed
>   password formats.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need parameters like these in your config: minRequiredPasswordLength, minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters and passwordStrengthRegularExpression.

From http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/05/11/Changing-the-Password-Complexity-in-ASP.NET-V2.0.aspx:

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                  connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                  enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                  enablePasswordReset="true"
                  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                  applicationName="/"
                  requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                  minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
                  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                  passwordFormat="Hashed"
                  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                  passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                  passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```